# JSON Saving Format

Tags: node.js, json

How to write information into json in this format?

```
{
    name_data: {
        "1": {
            name: "A",
        },
        "2": {
            name: "B",
        },
        "3": {
            name: "C",
        },
        "4": {
            name: "D",
        }
    }
}
```

Currently this is how I write information into json

```
client.reqs[1] = {
   name: "A",
   
}
fs.writeFile("./Database/reqs.json", JSON.stringify(client.reqs, null, 4), err => {
   if (err) throw err;
})
```

And this is the resulting format in json

```
{
  "1": {
    "name": "A",
  },
  "2": {
    "name": "A",
  },
  "3": {
    "name": "A",
  },
  "4": {
    "name": "A",
  }
}
```

Can somebody give answers, websites, or documentation that can help me answer my question?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? The indentation?

Comment: the way(format) the file is saved into json

Comment: im confused about what you are asking. Are you wanting the name_data ?

Comment: yeah I want the name_data on the top of my json file

Comment: I have upvoted a solution from @blaumeise20 below that should solve the problem you are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `JSON.stringify(client.reqs, null, "    ")`

The other thing you want to is not directly possible, it is more JavaScript than JSON. You cannot remove the quotes from the keys, because it would be invalid JSON.

For having the name_data on top level, do this (indentation change is included in this example):

```js
fs.writeFile("./Database/reqs.json", JSON.stringify({ name_data: client.reqs }, null, 4), err => {
   if (err) throw err;                               // ^ this adds name_data
})
```

Answer (score 0):

for the custom object key name
all you have to do is just to add ["the name you want"] : value

so I assume there will be something like

```
for(let i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
   client.reqs[i] = {
      [i]: "A",
   }
}
```

Comment: yes, but for now i am more concerned on the format of writing into json